# README is deformed in npmjs but appears in github

Tags: github, npm, package, markdown, readme

The readme file is represented as a binary file in npmjs.com but not in github.com

### screeshot:

[image]

### Url to the package

- github: https://github.com/scicave/rakam
- npmjs: https://npmjs.com/package/rakam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `README.md` is encoded as little-endian UTF-16, with mixed line endings:

```
$ file README.md 
README.md: Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text, with very long lines, with CRLF, CR line terminators
```

UTF-16 is fairly uncommon these days; UTF-8 has largely replaced it. Consider re-encoding your file as UTF-8, normalizing your line endings, and re-publishing.